# Python Difference between Account created date and current date

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

so I'm trying to calculate how long my discord account has existed. I am taking the datetime.today() value and dividing it by the date account was created.

```
createdDate = datetime(member.created_at.year, member.created_at.month, member.created_at.day)
todayDate = datetime(datetime.today().year, datetime.today().month, datetime.today().day)

diff = (todayDate - createdDate)
seconds = diff.total_seconds()
minutes = math.floor(seconds / 60)
hours = math.floor(minutes / 60)
minutes = math.floor(minutes - (hours * 60))
days = math.floor(hours / 24)
hours = math.floor(hours - (days * 24))
months = math.floor(days / 30)
days = math.floor(days - (months * 30))
years = math.floor(months / 12)
months = math.floor(months - (years * 12))

if (years < 0):
    years = years * - 1
if (months < 0):
    months = months * - 1
if (days < 0):
    days = days * - 1
if (hours < 0):
    hours = hours * - 1
if (minutes < 0):
    minutes = minutes * - 1

await ctx.send(f"{member.created_at.__format__(f'%B %d %Y @ %I:%M %p [{years} year(s), {months} month(s), {days} day(s), {hours} hour(s), {minutes} minutes]')}")
```

I use online calculators to double-check the math and my numbers seem a little off from what I'm trying to accomplish. Could someone help me out?

Comment: Just from looking at the beginning, member.created_at should already be a date time object, so you can calculate datetime.now() - member.created_at and calculate backwards from the result.

Comment: Another problem is that not every month has 30 days.

Comment: Doing your own date arithmetic is very hard to get right. Fortunately, you don't have to. `datetime`s understand subtraction.  Just do `todayDate-createdDate`.